# B2C Custom E-Mail verification: Tell the user what they need to do

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

We are currently evaluating the new feature (currently public preview) to do [custom e-mail verification in AAD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email)

Our initial testing with this feature was very positive. However, we fear that some of our users may not fully understand that they are receiving an e-mail and have to check their inbox. The "default" verification mechanism shows a message (key: "ver_info_msg") like this:

> Verification code has been sent to your inbox. Please copy it to the input box below.

The example shows no dedicated message to the user, it only shows the new controls.

[image]

Is there a way to get a localized message to the user for this? Localization via the usual mechanisms would be great. I understand that it is probably not trivial, since the one-time-password provider can be used in a number of ways - not only for custom e-mails - but it would be great to have the ability to give the user some feedback.

Are there some more UserMessages available for this? My current workaround is to localize the description and the placeholder for the "Verification Code" field, but this is less visible for the user.

```xml
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">VerifyCode</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessage.VerificationHasExpired">You have exceed the maximum time allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessage.MaxRetryAttemped">You have exceed the number of retries allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessage.InvalidCode">You have entered the wrong code.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessage.ServerError">Cannot verify the code, please try again later.</Item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature has been added in the meantime. It works just like the old verification message. Localization can be done via the string id `verification_control_code_sent`